# Jquery Validate String - only allowing numbers and specific characters

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

How do I validate a string to only allow numbers and * and # ?

Currently I've got..

```
    $('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(){
        var str = $(this).val(); 
});
```

I'd like to say if str contains anything other that `/[0-9*#]/` alert('error')

My mind has gone blank on how to do this..

The validation should only allow numbers and * and #  or a blank entry.

it doesn't matter the  order if an invalid character appears anywhere in the string it should error.

Thanks

Comment: `if (!/[0-9*#]/.test($(this).val()))`?

Comment: I should also add the result could be empty

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks. That doesn't work if the string start with a valid character. eg: 099AH779 would be allowed, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Please provide some fiddle with sample inputs and expected behavior.

Comment: @mplungjan. Thanks this seems to work: `if (reg.test(str) == false && str.trim() != '') console.log ('error')`

Comment: I converted my regex comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9*#]+$'); 
if (str.trim() !="" && !reg.test(str)) {
  alert("Error");
}
```

change `str.trim() !=""` to `$.trim(str) !=""` for jQuery

Comment: Thanks. That has help me.